# Double counting within sequences and arrangements

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Say we are forming sequences of numbers in the interval [0-9], lengths of (2x) where x is a value from [1,5].  So we form sequences of 2, 4, 6, 8, and 10 numbers.
A successful sequence is a sequence where at least half of the elements, (at least x of the elements), are the same number consecutively.  What is the total of 2, 4, 6, 8, and 10 number sequences that are successful?

Example: 2234 is successful.  3131 is not. 12 is successful. 2233 is successful. 2223 is successful.

Solution attempt:  My original plan was to choose 1 of the 10 numbers to have x times in a row, so 10 choices.

My second step was to choose the starting location of the x-length piece, and the x-length piece can be started at either the first position, all the way up to the x+1 position in the 2x length sequence.  So there are x+1 choices for the starting point of the x-length sequence.

My third step was to choose 1 of 10 letters for each of the remaining x slots, but now I realize I am double counting.

For example, the sequence 1122 could be obtained by choosing 11 as our x length sequence, placing it in the first slot, and happening to choose 2s to fill the remaining slots.
1122 could also be obtained by choosing 2 for the x length sequence, placing it in the third (x+1) slot, and happening to choose 1s to fill the rest.

I am assuming this is some sort of summation for values of x 1,2,3,4,5 or 2x, 2,4,6,8,10.  However, I am unsure of how to account for double counting in a way that is applicable to the general pattern of the scenario.  This isn't exactly something I feel should be solved with brute force.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So a sequence is 'successful' if and only if it contains a subsequence of length $x$, which is entirely made up of one integer from [0..9]?

Comment: For example, is 345558 successful?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: At least length x, so 345555 is also successful.

Comment: Did you delete your answer? I had intended to mark it accepted but you seem to have removed it.

Comment: Yes. I was unsure of it so I checked for $x=2$ in python and it turned out to be incorrect. I'l put it back when it's fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here  we  use *[generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function)*  to derive  the  number of successful sequences of length $2x$ containing $x$ consecutive  equal  characters,  $x\in\{2,3,4,5\}$ over a $10$ character alphabet.

But before that we consider the special, simple case $x=1$.

> **Case   $x=1$:**  Each word   having length $2x=2$ is a successful sequence. So  there  are
>   \begin{align*}
> 10^2=\color{bue}{100}
> \end{align*}
>   different words.

We continue by stating a generating function which counts words of a $10$ character alphabet with *no* consecutive equal characters at all.

These words are called Smirnov or Carlitz words. See example III.24 *Smirnov words* from *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/books.html)* by Philippe Flajolet and Robert Sedgewick for more information.

> The generating function $A(z)$ counting Smirnov words over a $10$ character alphabet is according to the reference 
>   \begin{align*}
>   A(z)&=\left(1-\frac{10z}{1+z}\right)^{-1}
> \end{align*}
>
> The coefficient of $z^n$ of $A(z)$ gives the number of Smirnov words of length $n$.

Based upon $A(z)$ we generate all words over the $10$ character alphabet which contain for $x\in \{2,3,4,5\}$ no more than $x-1$ consecutive equal characters. This means each character can be replaced with one up to $x-1$ characters.

\begin{align*}
z\longrightarrow z+z^2+z^3+\cdots+z^{x-1}=\frac{z(1-z^{x-1})}{1-z}
\end{align*}
in the  generating function $A(z)$.

> We obtain this way a generating function $B(z)=A\left(\frac{z(1-z^{x-1})}{1-z}\right)$ with
>   \begin{align*}
> B(z)&=\left(1-\frac{10\cdot \frac{z(1-z^{x-1})}{1-z}}{1+\frac{z(1-z^{x-1})}{1-z}}\right)^{-1}=\frac{1-z^x}{1-10z+9z^x}\\
> \end{align*}
>   The coefficient of $z^{2x}$ of $B(z)$ gives   the  number  of words which contain  *less* than $x$ consecutive equal characters.

The number of *all* words over a $10$ character alphabet  is given by
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (10z)^j=\frac{1}{1-10z}
\end{align*}

> We conclude the generating function $C_x(z)$ with
>   \begin{align*}
> C_x(z)=\frac{1}{1-10z}-\frac{1-z^x}{1-10z+9z^x}\qquad\qquad x\in\{2,3,4,5\}
> \end{align*}
>   counts the words which contains *runs* of length $x$, i.e. words having at least $x$ consecutive equal characters.

The number of successful sequences of length $2x$ is 
\begin{align*}
[z^{2x}]C_x(z)\qquad\qquad x\in\{2,3,4,5\}
\end{align*}

> In the following we obtain the series expansions below with some help of Wolfram Alpha
>
> **Case x=2:**
>
> The number of successful sequences of length $2x=4$ is
>   \begin{align*}
> [z^4]C_2(x)&=[z^4]\left(\frac{1}{1-10z}-\frac{1-z^2}{1-10z+9z^2}\right)\\
> &=[z^4]\left(10z^2+190z^3+2710z^4+34390z^5+\cdots\right)\\
> &=\color{blue}{2710}
> \end{align*}
>
> **Case x=3:**
>
> The number of successful sequences of length $2x=6$ is
>   \begin{align*}
> [z^6]C_3(x)&=[z^6]\left(\frac{1}{1-10z}-\frac{1-z^3}{1-10z+9z^3}\right)\\
> &=[z^6]\left(10z^3+190z^4+2800z^5+36910z^6+\cdots\right)\\
> &=\color{blue}{36910}
> \end{align*}
>
> **Case x=4:**
>
> The number of successful sequences of length $2x=8$ is
>   \begin{align*}
> [z^8]C_4(x)&=[z^8]\left(\frac{1}{1-10z}-\frac{1-z^4}{1-10z+9z^4}\right)\\
> &=[z^8]\left(10z^4+190z^5+2800z^6+37000z^7+459910z^8+\cdots\right)\\
> &=\color{blue}{459910}
> \end{align*}
>
> **Case x=5:**
>
> The number of successful sequences of length $2x=10$ is
>   \begin{align*}
> [z^{10}]C_5(x)&=[z^{10}]\left(\frac{1}{1-10z}-\frac{1-z^5}{1-10z+9z^5}\right)\\
> &=[z^{10}]\left(10z^5+190z^6+2800z^7+37000z^8+460000z^9+5499910z^{10}+\cdots\right)\\
> &=\color{blue}{5499910}
> \end{align*}

Adding all   the results we finally obtain

> The  number of successful sequences is
>   \begin{align*}
> 100+\sum_{j=2}^5[z^{2j}]C_j(x)&=100+2710+36910+459910+5499910\\
> &=\color{blue}{5999540}
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

As you ask for a sequence of length x, there are not many ways to have two sequences of distinct numbers in a sequence of length 2x. Precisely, you can chose 10 numbers for the first sequence, and 9 for the second, so 90 in total.

What is more difficult are longer sequences of the same number, for instance 1112 is counted 2 times, and 1111 even 3 times.

To avoid double counting these sequences, count the number of sequences of length x, and subtract the number of sequences of length x+1. A sequence of length x+k is now counted exactly once: you add it k+1 times when you count the sequences of length x, and subtract it k times when you subtract the sequences of length x+k.

To have the answer you want, you still have to count the possibilities of x and x+1 sequences for every x, subtract the possibilities of two sequences of different numbers and add all together, but I assume this is not considered as brute force.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a valid string containing $x$-tuple of twos, and an extra $n\ (0\leq n\leq x)$ number of twos. Thus you end up with exactly $(x-n)$ non-two symbols(of which there are $9^{x-n}$ possibilities) in the string. The $x$-tuple could be anywhere in the $(x-n+1)$ positions between/beyond these symbols.

The only positions left to be enumerated now are for the extra $n$ twos; these can go into any combination of $(x-n+2)$ places between the objects we have so far. Take a look at the partition adjacent to the $x$-tuple on the left and the one on the right. It should not matter if we assign $2$ twos to the one on the left and a single two to the one on the right, the end result is that you end up with a $(x+3)$-tuple of twos. <s>**(**Old explanation: This means we are overcounting by a factor of two. So remember to divide the above binomial coefficient by $2$.**</s> **Not true when n=0; also not true if both the partitions are assigned zero.)

So the two partitions may be combined into one. Note that multiple twos may occupy a single position here, so we are looking for the number of weak compositions of $n$ twos into $(x-n+1)$ partitions, which is:
$$
\binom{n+(x-n+1)-1}{n} = \binom{x}{n}
$$

Now put everything together:

$$
10\sum_{n=0}^{x} 9^{x-n}(x-n+1) \binom{x}{n}
$$
This still overcounts by exactly 90. (verified for each of $x=1,2,3,4$)

If you do a few examples by hand you'll notice that it double counts every case where a sequence consists of two parts: an $x$-tuple of one symbol, and an $x$-tuple of another symbol. For example, $x=2, n=0$: The sequence 2233 will be counted twice; once while counting sequences with $x$-tuple of $2$'s and again while counting $x$-tuple of $3$'s.
Accounting for every such permutation, we have: 
$$
10\sum_{n=0}^{x}\left\{ 9^{x-n}(x-n+1) \binom{x}{n} \right\} - \left(10 \right)_2
$$